# How explicitly reference type cast is helpful in java?

Tags: java

I wish to know which are case where java reference casting is helpful?

I tried with a parent and child class and verified that we don't need any casting when parent class object is assigned object of child class.
But reverse it not working like assigning object of parent class to object of child class, it give compile time error like "error: incompatible types: Person cannot be converted to Student   Student student2 = person1;"

Once I do explicit casting the compiling works but it fail at run time with exception "java.lang.ClassCastException: Person cannot be cast to Student". I could not understand if casting is not going to work at run time what is benefit of providing this feature or is there any case where it is working and helpful.

```
class Person {

    private String name;

    Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}

class Student extends Person {

    private int rollNo;

    Student(String name, int rollNo) {
        super(name);
        this.rollNo = rollNo;
    }

    public int getRollNo() {
        return rollNo;
    }
}
class Hello {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person person1 = new Person("person1");
        Student student1 = new Student("student1", 11);
        tudent student2 = (Student) person1;

    }
}
```

Comment: A Student can be used where you want a Person because it has a name, and that's all that's needed. A Person can't be used where you want a Student, however, because it isn't required to have a roll number.

Comment: Do the following assignment, and you'll understand: write a method foo taking an object as argument. If the object is an Integer, then multiply its value by 10 and print the result. If it's a String, then print its first character. Otherwise, print "what?".

Answer (score 0):

There are two things to think about when looking at an object:

1. the object’s **compile-time type**, i.e. its declared type;
2. the object’s **runtime type**, i.e. what type it *actually* is when your program is running.

These are the rules:

1. An object declared as a child class can be assigned to a reference of a parent class; no explicit cast needed.
2. An object declared as a parent class can be explicitly cast to a child class only if the object is actually a child-class object at runtime.

Example:

```
private static void displayPerson(Person person) {
    System.out.println(person.name);
}

private static void displayStudent(Student student) {
    System.out.println(student.name + ": " + student.grade);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Student student = new Student();
    displayPerson(student);  // rule 1

    Person student2 = new Student();  // declared type is Person, runtime type is Student
    displayStudent(student2);  // ERROR - won't compile
    displayStudent((Student) student2);  // rule 2 - cast is required
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cast to a 'more abstract type' whenever you want. For instance `Student` into `Person`.

Everywhere in your source code, it will be better to work with most abstract types. The main reason is that it will allow to change implementation without having to change the calling source code, or the methods' signature.

For instance, think about changing implementation use from a HashMap to a LinkedHashMap without having to change anything else because you are working only with Map generic type.

Even if lower cast is allowed (the one you tried: `Person` into `Student`), it is generally not recommended and generally means there is an issue in your classes design.

To conclude, because it is a `runtime` operation, you will learn it is not possible during execution instead of `compilation` time.